# Converting a jQuery datepicker to an Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I currently have a simple datepicker directive I use:

```
app.directive('pbDatetimepicker', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  require: 'ngModel',
  scope: {
    ngModel: '='
  },
  link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    element.datetimepicker(scope.ngModel);
  }
 };
});
```

However, that was for an **empty** datepicker.  I need to fill it in with defaults of today and, for one, today -30 days.  Here's the jQuery I used to do this:

```
$('#datepickerFrom').datetimepicker({
  pickTime: false,
  defaultDate: moment().subtract(30, 'days')
});
$('#datepickerTo').datetimepicker({
  pickTime: false,
  defaultDate: moment()
});
```

So I presume I can use custom attributes for options like that, but can someone point out the proper syntax?

Comment: Did you see http://angular-ui.github.io/ ? Specifically the [ui-date module](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date)

Comment: Yes, but we've already got CSS and such for the other datepicker, and don't really want to use jQuery UI either. Thanks.